# Optimize Groupby.apply() with user defined functions or vectorized function alternatives

Tags: pandas, numpy, apply, pandas-groupby

I am trying to optimize or avoid pandas Groupby.apply() method that takes my user defined function and applys it for every ID

Pandas version:0.23.4

Initial Dataframe

```
ID    Val1   Val2  Val3
1111  2      2      3
1111  NAN    9     10
1111  NAN    7      4
2222  NAN    2      3
2222  3      2      3
3333  6    NAN      5
3333  NAN    2      3
```

I groupby at ID level and call apply function which operates a user defined function

```py
df_dedup = df.groupby('ID').apply(lambda x : my_func(data = x))
```

My function my_func removes duplicates at ID level by choosing the one with highest non-missing values.
If the number of non-missing values are same (Eg: ID 3333) then I randomly pick one.

```
ID    Val1   Val2  Val3
1111  2      2      3  (This will be picked, highest non-missing ID)
1111  NAN    9     10
1111  NAN    7      4

2222  NAN    2      3
2222  3      2      3 (This will be picked, highest non-missing ID)

3333  6    NAN      5
3333  NAN    2      3 (Random Pick)
```

apply() conveniently aggregates all the 3 ID's and resulting data frame is

```
Final De-duped Dataframe 

ID    Val1   Val2  Val3
1111  2      2     3
2222  3      2     3
3333  NAN    2     3
```

Now, 
How do I do this without using groupby.apply() or apply() ?
Is there an alternative ?

It runs forever
1 Million records ran for ~20 Minutes

Answer (score 1):

Here is on way, split the dataframe by two , based on your condition , one have `nan` for all row or some row dose not contain `nan`, then we treat them different.

```
s1=df.isnull().any(1).groupby(df['ID']).transform('all')
df1=df[s1];df2=df[~s1]
df1=df1.sort_values(['Val3']).drop_duplicates('ID',keep='last')
df2=df2.groupby('ID').apply(pd.DataFrame.sample,n=1).reset_index(level=0,drop=True)
df=pd.concat([df1,df2]).sort_index()
df
Out[178]: 
     ID Val1 Val2  Val3
0  1111    2    2     3
4  2222    3    2     3
5  3333    6  NaN     5
```

Comment: For a large dataframe `idxmax()` would be a better choice than `sort_value().drop_duplicates()`.

Comment: @WeNYoBen, I see your Idea. Thankyou, I am going to start adopting it. But, If a certain row has more non-missing values it should be picked. Random picking should only be a tie-breaker if we have same number of non-missing values.
For example

`3333  6    NAN      NAN` 
       
`3333  NAN    2      3 .     (This should be picked)`
Can you explain how that can be addressed ?